# Are these functions Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

let's consider the function 
$$f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^+, \quad f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{-a} & x \in \mathbb{Q} \; \text{and} \; x>0\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$ 
for some $a \geq 1$.

Is it correct to conclude that this function is Lebesgue integrable, since $f$  differs from the constant function $g (x) = 0$ only on a null set?

The function
$$\tilde{f}: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^+, \quad \tilde{f}(x) = \begin{cases} x^{-a} & x \in \mathbb{Q}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$ 
differs from $f$ only on a null set, but is not defined at $x=0$. Is it still possible to make sense of the Lebesgue integral of $\tilde{f}$ over the closed interval $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: In both the cases, the functions are equal to $0$ almost everywhere. So the functions are lebesgue integrable and the integral too is $0$

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi what happens if the rationals and irrationals are interchanged, as in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208459/lebesgue-integral-of-a-piecewise-defined-function-defined-on-irrationals-and-rat)

Comment: I see your question has been answered now. Are you still confused? @vidyarthi